# How do I get Apple to accept my account passwords?

Tags: password, bug

My Mac has started asking for passwords to several of my (non-Apple) accounts (listed in Settings > Accounts), which until recently have been working fine. Entering these passwords (for several different accounts with several different providers) is always rejected with

> Unable to verify account name or password

I've verified that all of the passwords I'm providing are correct and work by trying them on other devices or accessing them in ways that do not involve Apple's settings. I've also confirmed that this makes a mess of the user of these (and Apple's) services: e.g., while mail syncs, content is blank (or Messages fails to sync with the previous several days activities).

How do I fix this? How can it even come about?!

Comment: What do you mean by "various accounts"?  Are you having trouble logging into your Mac?  Your iCloud/AppleID account?  As written, it's difficult to determine exactly what the problem is.

Comment: @Allan Clarified: see edit.

Comment: Have you tried removing the account and adding it back in?

Comment: @Allan No, why should that suddenly be necessary?

Comment: this is to do diagnostics.  Something got corrupted, and we're trying to figure out what.

Comment: @Allan OK, tried that and got the same error when attempting to add the account back: sow now I can't get any mail on that account at all!

Comment: Create a new user account, then add your email account there.  See if the problem persists

Comment: @Allan A new *Mac* user account? The account(s) in question work on other Macs and other devices, and via browsers.

Comment: If, by chance, you are referring to *Google Accounts* in "System Preferences">"*Internet* Accounts", then [this might help](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/356013/2418).

Comment: @Asmus No, my Google accounts seem to be OK. The problem seems mostly with Exchange.